# Getting strings from an array, replacing them and placing them in table

Tags: objective-c, replace, nsstring, nsarray

I am using the array "allscores" to parse the text label "scorelbl" in the populated table rows.

```
cell.scorelbl.text = [allscores objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] - 1];
```

The array prints

```
1
2
3
2
etc
```

But I want to include "/5" in each of the strings so that it prints in the cells:

```
1/5
2/5
3/5
2/5
etc
```

Then I use this to replace the strings from the array:

```
for (int i=0; i<[allscores count]; i++) {


                NSString* string = [allscores objectAtIndex:i];

                NSString * scorestringformatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/5", string];


                [allscores replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:scorestringformatted];
            }
```

I am trying it out but it prints:

```
1/5
2/5/5
3/5/5/5
2/5/5/5/5
etc
```

What should I fix?

**Updated outcome from suggested solution:**

When I print them for every row the /5 keep increasing. it starts with the desired one and ends up to

```
scores:
3/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,2/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,1/5/5/5/5/5/5,1


result: (
    "3/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "2/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    1
)


allscores: (
    "3/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "2/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    "1/5/5/5/5/5/5/5",
    1
)
```

Comment: When are you calling the method is the question. Also, why change the source data rather than just apply a formatting when you use the data (i.e. when you set the text on the cell)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
NSString *scores = [allscores componentsJoinedByString:@","];
scores = [scores stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"/5,"];

// Here is the result
NSArray *result = [scores componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Here `result` will become:

```
1/5
2/5
etc
```

use `result` as your datasource for UITableView or copy it to `allscore` then tableview's cell will display the above values in cell.

Comment: It still prints the same. I don't get it

Comment: post the value of `score`, `allscore` and `result` after applying my sample code. We need more from your side to troubleshoot.

Comment: Check post. Updates the result

Comment: I guess you have choosen the wrong event to execute this operation. Make sure you implement this methodology in a event that call only once. Did you do this is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: Yes that was the problem both mine and your solution work properly then.